# Why, when you click on unanswered questions, does it show questions with lots of answers?

Tags: server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)

I must be missing something, but it used to work on stackoverflow such that if you wanted to answer a question nobody has answered yet, you click on unanswered and there are questions with zero answers. No so much anymore.

Comment: Do we really need to answer this? Everybody here knows the answer, and the OP isn't registered here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate question, but:

If you look on the sidebar it says questions with no answers that have upvotes. StackOverflow considers this to be unanswered.